# Runnable subclasses, ordinary superclass, how to run the subclasses?

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, concurrency

Mind you, my design could be wrong completely so I'd accept any advice on that too.

I have a `Network` (a container of my own) and nodes in the net, but nodes can be routers or clients, so I have a node class that has various setters and getters common to any node, and Node is extended by Client and Router.

Now I have to start the nodes in their own threads, but Node is not runnable, that's one of the main differences between Routers and Clients, so these subclasses are implementing Runnable and have their own different neat run() methods.

The component starting up the nodes can call on `Node`s using the `Network`.

So how can I start/run the subclasses?

Comment: So what is one of the main differences between Routers and Clients? And why can't you make Node Runnable?

Comment: To keep things "simple" when initialising them, their behaviour is different but parameters are the same so i thought id initiate _a_ node, but run Clients and Routers

Comment: so if I understand correctly, it is just a design decision from your part. Well then, reverse the decision and make Node implement Runnable.

Comment: Yes, I think Andy White's answer below is cutting right in between, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Router and Client both implement Runnable, you could make Node implement Runnable at a higher level.  Node's run() method could either be a no-op, or you could make run() abstract in Node, to force the subclasses to implement it.

Comment: Niice, I went with abstract, no other changes were required and everything is again neat and streamlined, thanks!